# different background colours histogram

Tags: graphics, stata

I am wondering if anyone could provide a simple working example of a histogram that has different background colours for different values of "x". Something that would look like the following graph:
[image]

I cannot seem to find an easy way to do this, even though it is a fairly common visual tool when using histograms in a time context.

Comment: This isn't a histogram! In Stata terms it's a line plot.

Comment: Take a look at a user-written command called `nbercycles` to see how that is done in the context of time series.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please study https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve for future questions. Here in the question we see no data example, no attempt at code, no provenance for your graph.

This is reproducible:

```
webuse grunfeld, clear  
line invest year if company == 1 
twoway scatteri 0 1939 1500 1939 1500 1945 0 1945, recast(area) color(gs12) || line invest year if company == 1 , ytitle(invest) legend(order(1 "WW II") pos(11))
```

Steps:

1. Draw a `line` plot and decide what to highlight. It's a rectangle and you need the coordinates of the corners.
2. It's crucial to draw the rectangle first, as otherwise it will overwrite your `line` plot. Tastes and imperatives vary, but a light gray often works well.
3. The rectangle is drawn by specifying an "immediate" `scatteri` plot of the coordinates of the corners, but recasting to an `area` plot.
4. You need to reach in and fix the vertical axis title and very possibly the legend. Fine tuning: use the Graph Editor.
5. Optionally use `plotregion(margin(zero))` to remove the default area between the axes and the `plotregion`.

[image]